# Информация справа от названия класса в Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Подскажите, как убрать информацию справа от названий классов?

Intellij IDEA 2020.2.1 Ultimate

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

через меню Вид, подробнее описано на оф. сайте
[Show file size and modification timestamp](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html#show-filesize-timestamp)

Comment: Премного благодарен!